# How to add emoji picker with a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, emoji, picker

I'm working on Rails project. I have to add a emoji picker. I am using this library [emoji picker](https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker)

My application.erb.html is

```
    <p class="modal-content">
      <%= simple_form_for current_user, locals:{ controller: :dashboards ,action: :update } do |f| %>
      <p class="emoji-picker-container">
      <%= f.text_field :mood, data: { emojiable: true }, maxlength: 3, required: 'required', disabled: 'disabled' %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :mood_date, value: DateTime.now.to_date  %>
     </p>                  

     <%= f.button  :submit , value: t('button.submit') %>
     <% end %>
   </p>
```

inline script:

```
<script>
      $(function() {
          // Initializes and creates emoji set from sprite sheet
          window.emojiPicker = new EmojiPicker({
              emojiable_selector: '[data-emojiable=true]',
              assetsPath: 'http://onesignal.github.io/emoji-picker/lib/img/',
              popupButtonClasses: 'fa fa-smile-o'
          });

          window.emojiPicker.discover();
      });
</script>
```

Output as like:
[image]

But problem is here, I want that no pop will come and emoji box will be fixed as like:

[image]